# 2D JS Array assigning value for each index

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

This will be a stupid question. but why doesn't the following code assign 55 32 times to every corressponding index for j and k?

```
var array= new Array([]);
var rows=8; 
var cols=4; 
for (var j=0; j< 8; j++){
    for (var k=0; k<4; k++){
        array[j][k]=55;
        console.log(j, k)
    } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create `array`, you give it one value (`[]`) which goes to index `0`.

On the first loop around it, `j` is `0` and `array[j]` is an array and you can assign a value to whatever `array[j][k]` is.

On the second loop around it, `j` is `1` but `array[j]` is `undefined` and you can't assign a value to a property of `undefined`.

You need to create an array each time you go around the outer loop.

```
// var array= new Array([]);
// Don't mix array literal and Array constructor syntax.
// Only create one array here.
var array = [];
var rows=8; 
var cols=4; 
for (var j=0; j< 8; j++){
    // Create the array to hold the second dimension here
    array[j] = [];
    for (var k=0; k<4; k++){
        array[j][k]=55;
        console.log(j, k)
    }
}
```